# When I try to run this code I am getting time limit exceeded error and it's taking 1.01 ms to execute

Tags: java

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int t = sc.nextInt();
while(t-- > 0) {
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    while(true) {
        boolean ok = true;
        int num = n;
        while(num > 0) {
            if(ok && num % 3 == 2)
            ok = false;
            num = num / 3;
        }
        if (ok)
            break;
        ++n;
    }
    System.out.println(n);        
}
```

How can I optimize my code? This code is calculating an integer that can be represented as a sum of distinct powers of 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs in $O(N \log N)$. I think you are trying to solve [this question from CodeForces](https://codeforces.com/contest/1249/problem/C2). You have not mentioned the limits on $n$, but the question says that $n$ can be as large as $10^18$, an $O(N \log N)$ solution shall simply fail. Moreover, the question mentions there may be 500 queries, you need to solve the query 500 times within the time limit.

Note that, you receive "time limit exceeded" on those competitive programming sites, whenever the time is exceeded. It does not mean that your code executes in 1.01 seconds and you miss the limit by only 0.01 seconds. It just means that your code failed to execute in 1 second and stopped in 1.01 seconds. You cannot understand how long your code would take if it is allowed to run. You can do those checks on your own machine.

Having said all those, hint for the solution of the question:

Observation: Any number $n$ cannot be expressed as a sum of distinct powers of 3 if its base-3 representation contains "2".

Then, the question simply asks for the smallest integer greater than or equal to n and does not contain a "2" in its base-3 representation.

Consider the most significant "2" digit in the base-3 representation of the number. Take the digits before that "2". Count the number of digits "remaining" including the "2". Assume that number is in base-2, and add "1". Add "remaining" number of trailing zero digits to the number. Convert that "base-3" number to base-10 and output the result.

This algorithm runs in $O(log N)$, which should be sufficient to get an "Answer Correct".

A solution utilizing Java BigInteger is as follows:

```
void solve(long n) {
    final char[] chars = BigInteger.valueOf(n).toString(3).toCharArray();

    final int twoDigit = getTwoDigit(chars);
    if (twoDigit == -1) {
        System.out.println(n);
    } else {
        int remaining = chars.length - twoDigit;

        final BigInteger a;
        if (twoDigit == 0) {
            a = BigInteger.ONE;
        } else {
            a = new BigInteger(new String(chars, 0, twoDigit), 2).add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(a.toString(2), 3);
        BigInteger result = b.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(3).pow(remaining));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

private static int getTwoDigit(char[] chars) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == '2') {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```